# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' on CentOS 7

Tags: python, matplotlib, centos

Yes, I've installed a version of it.

Trying to run my Python script with `python36 program.py`.

I tried `sudo yum install python-matplotlib.x86_64`, and I get the following saying I already have it:

`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hmc.edu
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
 * epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.scalabledns.com
Package python-matplotlib-1.2.0-15.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

So I don't know what to do. I'm using `import matplotlib` for the import statement. Does anyone know what my issue could be?

Comment: I guess the lib is installed for Python 2. Check im there is a Python 3 version in package manager!

Comment: Can you install it through pip?

Comment: @KlausD. I checked and that's the only Python version of Matplotlib for me. Do you know the version I should install `and command itself`?

Comment: @JordanSinger I don't know if I should be using pip.

Comment: *" I don't know if I should be using pip"*: Type `pip3` in console window and report the result.

Comment: I can't think of many great reasons not to use pip to install a package. What is the limitation?

Comment: @JordanSinger At the installation FAQ page (https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html), it says to "To install Matplotlib at the system-level, we recommend that you use your distribution's package manager. This will guarantee that Matplotlib's dependencies will be installed as well". I want Matplotlib installed at the system level, so my thought process was to use YUM over all else.

Comment: Right below that, it does say "If, for some reason, you cannot use the package manager, you may use the wheels available on PyPI." This isn't something I would spin your wheels over, and if you aren't familiar with python package management, using yum could complicate your system environment.

Comment: @JordanSinger when trying `python -mpip install matplotlib` as it suggests at the site, the console tells me `Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (1.2.0)`. I need it for Python 3.6 though. When trying `python3 -mpip install matplotlib`, it says Matplotlib 3.0+ does not support Python 2.x, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, or 3.4. Beginning with Matplotlib 3.0, Python 3.5 and above is required. This may be due to an out of date pip.
Make sure you have pip >= 9.0.1.`.

Comment: @JordanSinger But my pip is up to date, as trying to update says `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (18.1)'. So I'm a bit lost as to what to try.

Comment: The output you have there tells me that you used python2.7's pip, and not python3. What are the outputs of `which python` and `which python3`?

Comment: @JordanSinger `/usr/bin/python`, and `/usr/bin/python3` respectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186811/discussion-between-jordan-singer-and-mr-mips).

Comment: After the chat, issue not fixed.